# C++ slow loop computation

Tags: c++, performance, loops, while-loop, montecarlo

I have the following loop for a monte-carlo computation I am performing:

the variables below are pre-computed/populated and is defined as:

```
    w_ = std::vector<std::vector<double>>(150000, std::vector<double>(800));
    C_ = Eigen::MatrixXd(800,800);
    Eigen::VectorXd a(800); 
    Eigen::VectorXd b(800);
```

The while loop is taking me about 570 seconds to compute.Just going by the the loops I understand that I have nPaths*m = 150,000 * 800 = 120,000,000 sets of computations happening (I have not taken into account the cdf computations handled by boost libraries).

I am a below average programmer and was wondering if there are any obvious mistakes which I am making which maybe slowing the computation down. Or is there any other way to handle the computation which can speed things up.

```
    int N(0);
    int nPaths(150000);
    int m(800);
    double Varsum(0.);
    double err;
    double delta;
    double v1, v2, v3, v4;

    Eigen::VectorXd d = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(m);
    Eigen::VectorXd e = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(m);
    Eigen::VectorXd f = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(m);
    Eigen::VectorXd y; 
    y0 = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(m);
    boost::math::normal G(0, 1.);
    d(0) = boost::math::cdf(G, a(0) / C_(0, 0));
    e(0) = boost::math::cdf(G, b(0) / C_(0, 0));
    f(0) = e(0) - d(0);  
    while (N < (nPaths-1))
    {
        y = y0;
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
        {
            v1 = d(i - 1) + w_[N][(i - 1)]*(e(i - 1) - d(i - 1));
            y(i - 1) = boost::math::quantile(G, v1);
            v2 = (a(i) - C_.row(i).dot(y)) / C_(i, i);
            v3 = (b(i) - C_.row(i).dot(y)) / C_(i, i);
            d(i) = boost::math::cdf(G, v2);
            e(i) = boost::math::cdf(G, v3);
            f(i) = (e(i) - d(i))*f(i - 1);
        }

        N++; 
        delta = (f(m-1) - Intsum) / N;
        Intsum += delta;
        Varsum = (N - 2)*Varsum / N + delta*delta;
        err = alpha_*std::sqrt(Varsum);
   }
```

Comment: Profile your code to see where it is spending its time.  If you use Linux see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913

Comment: Did you compile with full optimizations?  On Linux, pass `-O2` or `-O3` to the compiler command line.

Comment: The lack of thorough commenting in your code is an issue: it's hard to say how to improve code if you don't have a good explanation of what was intended. It would also be super-helpful if it was possible to compile the code in your question: as it is, guesswork is required to figure that out. To get helpful answers, provide the most helpful question you can.

Comment: Seems as if you are not using err inside the loop. So it should be enough to calculate it once at the end of your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code right, the running time is actually `O(nPaths*m*m)=10^11`, due to  the dot-product `C_.row(i).dot(y)` which needs `O(m)` operation.

You could speed up the program by factor of two by not calculating it twice:

```
double prod=C_.row(i).dot(y)   
v2 = (a(i) - prod) / C_(i, i);
v3 = (b(i) - prod) / C_(i, i);
```

but maybe compiler already does it for you.

The other thing is that `y` consists of zeros (at least at the beginning) so you don't have to do the full dot-product but only until current value of `i`. That should give another factor 2 speed up.

So taken into the account the sheer number of operation your timings are not so bad. There is some room for improvement of the code, but if you are interested in speeding up some orders of magnitude you probably should be thinking about changing your formulation.